# How does where clause of cumulative sum works?

Tags: mysql, sql

So, I have a table call order and consist of two result which consist of a value.

When I execute this query:

```
SELECT @running_total := @running_total + orders.myVal AS cumulative_sum
From orders JOIN
     (SELECT @running_total := 0) r
```

It return this result:

```
_____________________
|id | cumulative_sum |
|___|________________|
| 1 |             1  |
|___|________________|
| 2 |             3  |
|___|________________|
```

However when I add a where clause `WHERE @running_total <= 0.5`

which is

```
SELECT @running_total := @running_total + orders.myVal AS cumulative_sum
From orders JOIN (SELECT @running_total := 0) 
WHERE @running_total <= 0.5
```

Why does it return the same result?

In my knowledge, it shouldnt return any result as both of the result does not contain anything less than 0.5

Thanks

Comment: Instead of `WHERE @running_total <= 0.5` try with `HAVING cumulative_sum <= 0.5`

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Thanks but I just want to know how the original query works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TRY THIS:** I think, While you are checking the condition with `@running_total <= 0.5` at this time there isn't any value assigned in this variable so it's always be true and return value. Please check with `@running_total <= 0.2` also return true and check by `>` also you will understand what your are doing

```
SELECT * FROM (@running_total := @running_total + orders.myVal AS cumulative_sum 
From orders 
JOIN (SELECT @running_total := 0) r) t WHERE @running_total <= 0.5
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but I just want to know how the original query works

Comment: Please check the update, I have added the reason that why your query is not working properly.

Comment: In fact when i place > 0.5, it return nothing

Comment: Exactly, because variable doen't have any assigned value so that is never be `>0.5` and return false. Hope you understand my dear friend.

Answer (score 1):

When "Where" clause added on above which didn't satisfy the condition for a single record then also it always returns the first record, not the same resultset.

Please refer this example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc0a4/3

It seems that before assignment to the "@running_total" variable Where clause should be applied.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) on variables explains:

> In a `SELECT` statement, each select expression is evaluated only when
>   sent to the client.

In other words, the `WHERE` is evaluated *before* the `SELECT` is evaluated.  You have set the value of the variable of `0`, so all rows pass the condition.

As explained elsewhere, a subquery solves the problem.

I should also note that running the query without an `ORDER BY` means that the results are in an arbitrary, indeterminate order.